# SwiftUI: sheet will not present with Picker appeared

Tags: swift, swiftui

It may be a bug of SwiftUI?
There is a Picker component and two buttons in the ContentView. The first button is simply changing the "show" var to true and the second button change the var with a delay. The sheet should be present by tapping the buttons. But I found that if the Picker is tapped at first and keep nothing selected then only the button with delay can present the sheet. The button without delay will cause an error:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x14e80e400> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x14c819600> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x14c819600>) which is already presenting <_UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController: 0x14d63be90>.
```

After that, the sheet will never be able to present again. Is that the only solution (adding a delay) to avoid this situation?

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @State var picked = "1"
    let values = ["1", "2", "3"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $picked, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach (values, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(value)
                }
            }
            Text("⬆️ Tap me but don't select")
                .padding(.bottom, 120)
            Text("1. Tap Picker")
            Text("2. Tap show sheet button")
            Button("show sheet") {
                show = false
                show = true
            }
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)
            Button("show sheet with delay") {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    show = true
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $show, content: {
            Button("close") {
                show = false
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not replicate your issue. All works well for me, on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
Maybe the "bug" is on older systems.

Comment: I will try again with ios 16.3. thank you.